# Cannot access to the OSM Boundaries website

Tags: metadata, openstreetmap, reliability

I was using the [OSM Boundaries](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/) website to download shpfiles of boundaries and using them in QGIS:

[image: QGIS screenshot]

Today, when I was attempted to access this website I get this message and I get the same result from the [Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Boundaries) link.

[image: Browser screenshot]

I did not get this message from other OSM website, [like this one](http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/) that have shpfile of big cites around the world. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps because their https certificate is expired since July 05.

Comment: If so we need to wait for them to fix it?

Comment: I think yes, most likely they know...

Comment: You can always add an exception in your browser or try the http version?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this thread](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=58893).

As well as I understand, the maintainer will shutdown this domain.
One shoud use https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/ instead.